# Como consultar intervalos de datas de outra tabela?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela com intervalos de datas e outra com os dados das vendas. Como posso montar uma *query* que me traga os totais de vendas nos últimos 3 períodos a partir da  tabela `datas_periodos` ?

```
Tabela (datas_periodos): id_datas;  data1; data2;

id_datas;  data1;        data2;
192       2014-01-04   2014-02-01
193       2014-02-02   2014-03-01
```

---

```
Tabela (vendas): id_vendas; data_venda; vendedor; valor_vendas; 

id_vendas; data_venda; vendedor; valor_vendas;  
1953       2014-01-02  maria      30000,00
3444       2014-01-02  joao       15000,00
3212       2014-02-03  antonio    34202,00
```

Precisaria de uma saída assim:

```
data1          data2      valor total
2014-01-04   2014-02-01    150000,00
2014-02-02   2014-03-01    300000,00
```

Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Vc já tentou alguma coisa, `select * from tabela`. Se sim, edite sua pergunta para podermos melhor te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem nada de complicado:

```
Select data1, data2, SUM(valor_vendas) as vendas_periodo 
From datas_periodos, vendas
Where data_venda Between data1 and data2
Group by data1
```

Veja no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2baf5/2)

Comment: Grato pelo resposta, porem a tabela datas_peridos só tem informações de datas, a outra tabela tem as informações de vendas, gostaria de uma query que trouxesse as vendas a partir dos intervalos da tabela data_periodos

Comment: Mas é isso que esta query faz! Você foi ver no SQLFiddle?

Comment: Ué mas é isso que a query ta fazendo

Comment: Me desculpe, interpretei errado, realmente funcionou como o esperado, vc realmente esta corretíssimo em relação a query,

Comment: muito grato, funcionou perfeitamente.